# How do i get AndroidStudio to use JDK

Tags: android-studio, java-6

In trying to solve a headache (can't import javax.sound.sampled) I came across a post saying that AndroidStudio should be using the JDK, not the JRE.  Is this a thing?  And if so, how do I get it to use just the JDK?

Comment: Try to upgrade to AS 2.2, you can use Jaba 8 with it. Which platform do you use? On Linux, AS comes with JDK built in

Comment: I'm on Windows 10, and my last update of AS was a nightmare.  Surely there's a way to try with this version first?

Comment: Yes, AS supports side-by-side installation of 2.1 and 2.2. I recommend the last Dev. channel version